# Regex to check if sequence of characters exists before or after delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string

I have a string such as `ID123456_SIT,UAT` where `ID######` will always be hardcoded.

I need a python regex that will allow me to check whether `ID123456_` and (`SIT` or `UAT`) exists before (without a comma) **or** after a comma in a particular string.

Scenarios:

1. `ID123456_SIT,UAT` - should match with regex
2. `ID123456_UAT,SIT` - should match with regex
3. `ID123456_SIT` - should match with regex
4. `ID123456_UAT` - should match with regex
5. `ID123456_TRA,SIT,UAT` - should match with regex

As of right now the following only works if 1 comma is specified (1 & 2 above), but does not work for single values (3 & 4) if a comma is not specified (bottom 2 scenarios). Also does not work if there was more than 1 comma specified, at which point I should be checking if the word exists between any of the commas (Scenario 5):

- `(^ID123456_)(SIT|UAT),(SIT|UAT)` - works for Scenarios 1 & 2 only

Also open to other suggestions for solving the same problem: checking if ID123456 & SIT/UAT is present in a pandas column's values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to make part of the regex optional - `^ID123456_(?:SIT|UAT)(?:,(SIT|UAT))?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - How can I modify this to work for scenario 5 where there is a chance SIT or UAT do not appear in the first segment, but rather, in one of the later comma-separated segments?

Comment: Maybe `^ID123456_(?:SIT|UAT|TRA)(?:,(SIT|UAT))*`? See https://regex101.com/r/XQ0PDJ/1

Comment: `^ID123456_(?:[A-Z]{3},)*(SIT|UAT)\b` maybe?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The thing is that the regex needs to be created based on the initial string: ID123456_SIT,UAT. I need to check if the pattern exists in another string, but we don't know what the other string looks like so can't hardcode more words into the regex to account for every scenario. I simply need to check if ID123456_ & SIT/UAT are present anywhere in the string i am comparing the regex to.

Comment: `^ID123456_(?=.*(?:SIT|UAT))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - this seems to only match ID123456_ and nothing else when inputted into the link you provided.

Comment: @JvdV - Where does the {3} come into the picture? I can't hardcode to assume the string I am comparing the regex to will always have 3 segments (segment1,segment2,segment3); it can have N number of segments at which point I need to look for SIT or UAT in any of those segments

Comment: It matches all 5 strings, if you add `.*` at the end, you will match till end, see https://regex101.com/r/XQ0PDJ/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew with your .* it seems to answer the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way I could modify the accepted answer to check whether both only SIT AND UAT occur in the same string, without the ID123456_ prefix?  For example, if (SIT,UAT) is the input string, regex should result in TRUE if (SIT,UAT) or (UAT,SIT) is found. There can also be more than N elements: (N1,N2,N3) or (N3,N1,N2), but if N4 is present in the input list, regex should result to false. I’ll be happy to post as a different question if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^ID123456_(?=.*(?:SIT|UAT)).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQ0PDJ/2).

This matches

- `^` - start of string
- `ID123456_` - text that the string should start with
- `(?=.*(?:SIT|UAT))` - there must be either `SIT` or `UAT` after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `.*` - the rest of the line.